# How to show borderless Message box in WPF

Tags: wpf, wpf-controls

I want to show Message/Dialog box on clicking button, Message box should be border-less with one button.(Dialog box style should be same like creating Window with "None" style).

Comment: Just create your own message box window...

Comment: I am creating message box using System.Windows.MessageBox("text") but it's having border. What do you mean with own message box window.

Comment: see this http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/327212/Custom-Message-Box-in-VC?fid=1684582

Comment: Create a standard window instead of  System.Windows.MessageBox, then make it look like you want and use this as messagebox, Window.ShowDialog() behaves exactly the same way as a messagebbox

Comment: I am able to create standard window but how to set window style?

Comment: Set the attribute WindowStyle="None"